# Purpose of Maven versions:set removeSnapshot?

Tags: maven, version, maven-versions-plugin

The `versions-maven-plugin` `versions:set` goal show that there is a [`removeSnapshot`](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/set-mojo.html#removeSnapshot) parameter:

> **removeSnapshot:**
>   Whether to remove -SNAPSHOT from the existing version. If not set will default to false.
>
> ```
> Type: boolean
> Since: 2.10
> Required: No
> User Property: removeSnapshot
> Default: false
> ```

I have a Maven multi-module aggregation POM with all the versions in all the modules set to `0.2.0-SNAPSHOT`. I am ready to release (please don't tell me to use the Maven release plugin) and I want to change the version to `0.2.0`. So I try this:

```
mvn versions:set -DremoveSnapshot=true
```

Maven stops and asks me:

```
Enter the new version to set 0.2.0-SNAPSHOT:
```

Um, if I manually enter `0.2.0`, what's the point of having indicated `removeSnapshot=true`?

Comment: I can't reproduce that, on a project without modules (didn't test with, but that shouldn't matter), using version 2.3 of the plugin. Can you post the entire logs of the plugin execution?

Comment: @Garret seems to be working fine with [2.5.3](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-release-plugin/2.5.3) as well for multimodule project. Or if you can share further details.

Comment: @nullpointer What part of "please don't tell me to use the Maven release plugin" did you not understand? :D hehe I think you're talking about a different plugin.

Comment: ya my bad, [2.3](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.mojo/versions-maven-plugin/2.3) it is :P

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The version [2.3 of versions-maven-plugin](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.mojo/versions-maven-plugin/2.3), works fine for me while using

```
mvn versions:set -DremoveSnapshot=true
```

---

Also, though couldn't find it  documented anywhere but testing the behavior while using

```
<configuration>
      <removeSnapshot>true</removeSnapshot>
</configuration>
```

Or

```
mvn versions:set -DremoveSnapshot=true
```

I can say that if you try to set your new version from an existing `0.2.0-SNAPSHOT` to another `0.2.1-SNAPSHOT` or bump(`0.2.1)` up the version to something else. The parameter would restrict you to simply marking a release of the current SNAPSHOT version resulting in `0.2.0` anyhow.

---

So (with configuration for `removeSnapshot` marked as `true`)

```
mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=0.2.1
```

or

```
mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=0.2.1-SNAPSHOT
```

would result in generating

```
<version>0.2.0</version>
```

---

On the other hand be it `default` or explicitly set to `false` above commands would generate

```
<version>0.2.1</version>
```

and

```
<version>0.2.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

respectively.